# How to create a hole in a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing

I'm trying to use the tool "delete ring" in order to create a hole in a polygon. The geometry of the hole is another feature of the same shapefile

I cannot manage to delete the part of the polygone. Does someone have a tutorial or some explanation?

Comment: I would like to "Add Rings" but using other polygons. Example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue1k3b646ivqedo/holes.JPG I would like to delete the two selected polygons and create holes under them in the big polygon where they are. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Aitor You seem to still be active on GIS SE, whereas Lucien has not been seen here for 18 months.  If you or anyone else wants to try and get an Accept-able Answer (the current one seems to overlook the requirement that an existing feature should be used to create the hole rather than digitizing) then I recommend that you edit this Question to bring it back onto the active list.

Comment: Is there a way to add rings based on existing polygon feature classes? Or does one have to draw the new geometry?

Comment: Just had the same issue that I solved without having to manually trace the "add ring". I took screenshots to add to answer but just realised I don't have the internet points to add this as an answer, hence the comment. QGIS (2.18.8) has a "symmetrical difference" option under the Vector>Geoprocessing Tools that allowed me to cut a hole in one polygon using a second polygon.

Comment: With existing smaller polygons see:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282668/make-holes-in-a-polygon-from-existing-smaller-polygons

Answer (score 35):

You should be using `"Add Ring"` tool to create a hole in the polygon.

Just Select the "Add Ring" tool and digitize a hole inside the polygon. It will remove that part and create a hole.

[image]

Comment: for qgis 2.10 to enable the toolbar go : Edit -> Toolbar -> Check Adv. Digitizing.

Comment: For QGIS 2.18. it is located in the Advanced Digitizing toolbar.

Comment: What about if I already have two polygons (maybe quite complex)? I do not want to add new. I just want to subtract those two existing polygons to create a hole. Any hints?

Comment: For QGIS 3 it is also located in Advanced Digitizing Toolbar

Comment: In QGIS 3.16, first *Toggle Editing* then *Edit → Add Ring*

Comment: Works well but should be called "Create hole" or "Erase polygon". I guess the logic in the name is you are adding a hole/ring but it's counterintuitive. I came to this answer by searching for erase.