# Drawing polygons with holes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

In QGIS 2.18 I draw polygons on a certain grassland-type on aereal imagery. Sometimes, there are other landcover-types within the patches of interest, so I'd like to draw polygons with holes.

In the example, I want to exclude the small forest-patches within the grassland. Is there any procedure other than creating a new layer for everything I want to exclude and then clip my grassland-layer?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Advanced digitising `Add ring` tool

Turn on the Advanced Digitising Toolbar in `View > Toolbars > Advanced digitsing`, or `Edit > Add ring`

Then with the layer editable, click on the *Add ring* icon

[image]

and click away around the woodland, right-click to finish

If you then want to add a polygon to fill the hole, then use the *Add feature* in the normal way, but with `Settings > Snapping Options` set up so you can snap to the nodes of your ring so you don't end up with overlaps or gaps.

Comment: Just realised this had been asked before here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/how-to-create-a-hole-in-a-polygon-in-qgis so I expect this may get closed as a duplicate. I should have checked first.

Comment: The link leads exactly to this question - and I didn't find the same question here.

Comment: Sorry copied wrong link, have now edited my comment