# Polygon visibility with overlapping polygons QGIS 3.4

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, geometry

I am marking forestry boundaries over google satellite tiles.  The forest in question  has areas of farmland within the outer boundary.  One area of farmland has a patch of forestry within it's boundary.  I need to see the g sat tiles through rh hatching for forestry and lh hatching for farmland.  I have tried making farm and forestry separate layers but where farmland is I get crossed hatching.  I think I'm asking if it's possible to draw a polygon with a hole in the middle.

Comment: If your question is about creating/filling hole in polygon look at these answer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308659/creating-polygon-from-hole-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/how-to-create-a-hole-in-a-polygon-in-qgis

Comment: I have looked at the second of the links.  On my QGIS 3.4 there were no icons showing to cut a hole.  I added the Digitizing Tools Plugin but when I try to use it I get a message "CAD tools are not enabled for the current map tool" and the cursor remains a hand.  When I click on the Toggle Editing icon the Digitizing Tools icons will become active or grey out but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I needed to activate the toolbar.  That worked the plugin didn't.